# Определить сумму и количество положительных элементов, индексы которых делятся на 3 без остатка

Tags: java

Определить сумму и количество положительных элементов, индексы которых делятся на 3 без остатка.В одной строке вывести количество искомых элементов и их сумму, вычисленную с точностью до двух десятичных знаков.

Проблема:  Найдите ошибку , что не так?

Код:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
double sum=0,x=0;
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    x=sc.nextDouble();
     if(x>0 && x%3==0){       
         sum=sum+x;                
        count++;
    }
} System.out.println(count+" "+sum/3);
```

Comment: вы не задумывались над тем, как дробное число может делиться на 3 без остатка? sc.nextDouble() - измените это на nextInt()

Comment: на 3 без остатка должен делиться индекс числа, а не само число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс делится на 3, а не значение 
Кроме того на сайте используется нумерация с 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    if (i % 3 == 0 && x > 0) {
        sum = sum + x;
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.printf("%d %.2f", count, sum);
```

Comment: Есть сайт e-olymp , я прохожу там задания, мой код выдает ошибку. 
Вход должен быть :
6 -
6 7.5 2.1 2.0 0 -3
Выход:
1 2.10

У меня выход 1 2,0

Comment: "сумму, вычисленную с точностью до двух десятичных знаков." Вам надо использовать форматированный вывод.

Comment: System.out.printf("%d",sum/3);  Выдает ошибку - IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double

Comment: Попробуйте System.out.printf("%d %.2f", count, sum);

Comment: Зачем вы делите сумму на 3?

Comment: Выход: System.out.printf("%d %.2f",count,sum);     1   6,00  -  должно быть 1  2,10

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощ , ответ найден  -   becouse

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
double sum = 0, x = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    if (i % 3 == 0 && x > 0) {
        sum = sum + x;
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("%d %.2f", count, sum);
```

Comment: Выход и должен быть 1 2,00 при входе 6 -6 7.5 2.1 2.0 0 -3, а не как не 1 2.10

Comment: Тогда выходет что сайт с ответом путает меня?

Comment: Ну смотрите сами, из данного набора чисел, в сумму попадает только одно число, и это двойка. У нее индекс равен 3 и оно положительное. Соответственно сумма может быть равной только 2.00

Comment: Это, конечно, если учитывать, что индекс 0 соответствует элементу -6